# How to add, then reference a div with ID and then remove it on JS. (Web)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am trying to hide the scrollbar when opening a fullscreen menu. That part I got working, what Im missing is getting the same button that hides the scrollbar to make it appear back again (removing the .no-scroll from the body). Here is my failed attempt, looks like the second function is not working.

```
$('.menu_container').on('click', function(){
  $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
  $('.menu_container').attr('id', 'menu_close');
});

$('#menu_close').on('click', function(){
  $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
  $('#menu_close').removeAttr('menu_close');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your event handlers are attached as soon as the DOM is loaded. And when this happens, there's no element with id #menu_close yet (since it's added only after you click on .menu_container), so the second event handler is not attached to anything.

You could move it up inside the first function like this:

```
$('.menu_container').on('click', function(){
  $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
  $('.menu_container').attr('id', 'menu_close');

  $('#menu_close').on('click', function(){
    $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
    $('#menu_close').removeAttr('menu_close');
  });
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that every time `.menu_container` is clicked you're adding another event handler to `#menu_close`. A better approach would be to use a delegated event handler in this case.

Comment: True. That can be worked around by using .one() instead of .on()

Comment: That went smooth! Only thing is I can't get the function to remove the ID, even when using .one() Perhaps if I give it another ID that gets removed with the first function then added back again

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've removed the id which is how you're finding the element.

If you want to add and remove a class that makes your  scrollable use:

```
$( 'body' ).addClass( 'no-scroll' );
```

And:

```
$( 'body' ).removeClass( 'no-scroll' );
```